# How to open the accordion for each item when click on icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an accordion type component in reactjs In this When I open the first toggle, only toggle one content should open, when clicked on second toggle then the toggle one content should close and only toggle second content should be open(Only one toggle should be open at a time) . But in my case everytime same div is getting open. I don't know where I did wrong? and how to solve it?.  below is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaPlus, FaMinus } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./FAQ.scss";
import { Collapse } from "reactstrap";

const Question = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

    return (
        <div className="question">
            <div>
                <button onClick={toggle}>
                    {isOpen ? <FaMinus /> : <FaPlus />}
                </button>
            </div>
            <div onClick={toggle} className='title'>
                {props.question}
            </div>
                <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} className='content'>
                    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for 
                    those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" 
                    by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English 
                    versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
                </Collapse>
            <hr />
        </div>
    );
};

function FAQ() {
    return (
        <div className="faq" id='faq'>
            <h2>F.A.Q.</h2>
            <div className="faq-section">
                <Question question="Question one" />
                <Question question="Question two" />
                <Question question="Question three" />
                <Question question="Question four" />
                <Question question="Question five" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FAQ;
```

The screenshot is given in the below  [image]

**UPDATE THE QUESTION**

Below is the link of a website the have the FAQ section in the bottom, I am trying to make the toggle feature as they have.
[FAQ section in the bottom of this website](https://7edge.com/web-development-services)

Comment: Each question appears to have its own `isOpen` state, so they should all be independent from one another. I don't see how it's possible for one to toggle all the others.

Comment: @DrewReese I am trying to open div one when I clicked on toggle first same for others also

Comment: `But in my case everytime same div is getting open`, or `open div one when I clicked on toggle first same for others also` . it is not clear what you want to do

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I want to if I clicked on first toggle- first div, second toggle- second div, means I want to open different div on different toggle. in my case everytime same div is getting open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that all `Question` components have their own state, independent of the others.

## Solution

If you want to only open one `Question` at-a-time then the state needs to be lifted and declared in `FAQ`. This is so there's a single source of truth for what is opened/expanded.

FAQ

Move the `isOpen` state and toggle handler to this parent component. Use an "id" to toggle on/off the question component you want to expand. Pass an `isOpen` and `toggle` props to each `Question` component and handle the id logic here.

```
function FAQ() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(null);

  const toggleOpen = id => () => setIsOpen(
    isOpen => isOpen === id ? null : id,
  );

  return (
    <div className="faq" id='faq'>
      <h2>F.A.Q.</h2>
      <div className="faq-section">
        <Question
          question="Question one"
          isOpen={isOpen === 0}
          toggle={toggleOpen(0)}
        />
        <Question
          question="Question two"
          isOpen={isOpen === 1}
          toggle={toggleOpen(1)}
        />
        <Question
          question="Question three"
          isOpen={isOpen === 2}
          toggle={toggleOpen(2)}
        />
        <Question
          question="Question four"
          isOpen={isOpen === 3}
          toggle={toggleOpen(3)}
        />
        <Question
          question="Question five"
          isOpen={isOpen === 4}
          toggle={toggleOpen(4)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Question

Call/consume the `isOpen` and `toggle` from the passed props.

```
const Question = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="question">
      <div>
        <button onClick={props.toggle}>
          {props.isOpen ? <FaMinus /> : <FaPlus />}
        </button>
      </div>
      <div onClick={props.toggle} className='title'>
        {props.question}
      </div>
      <Collapse isOpen={props.isOpen} className='content'>
        ....
      </Collapse>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Update

Ok, since it seems you are struggling with the issue of rendering the same "content" in each `Question` component I suggest you load up all your questions and content into an array and map them instead of hardcoding the JSX.

FAQ

```
const faqData = [
  {
    question: "Question one",
    content: <div> .... I'm content .... </div>, // <-- anything renderable as a child
  },
  ... etc...
];

function FAQ() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(null);

  const toggleOpen = id => () => setIsOpen(
    isOpen => isOpen === id ? null : id,
  );

  return (
    <div className="faq" id='faq'>
      <h2>F.A.Q.</h2>
      <div className="faq-section">
        {faqData.map(({ content, question}, index) => (
          <Question
            key={index}
            content={content}
            question={question}
            isOpen={isOpen === index}
            toggle={toggleOpen(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Question

```
const Question = ({ content, question, isOpen, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <div className="question">
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggle}>
          {isOpen ? <FaMinus /> : <FaPlus />}
        </button>
      </div>
      <div onClick={toggle} className='title'>
        {question}
      </div>
      <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} className='content'>
        {content}
      </Collapse>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-open-the-accordion-for-each-item-when-click-on-icon]

And just in case you missed it, you also need to import the bootstrap CSS somewhere in your project to get the bootstrap styles, transitions, and animations working.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you please check out the question I have UPDATED with a demo of the toggle feature

Comment: @Inception_K [Here](https://7edge.com/web-development-services)? Seems to function as you described, 1 expansion at-a-time. Do you have some concern?

Comment: Yes 1 expansion at-a-time

Comment: @Inception_K Sorry, am I misunderstanding something? Is one expansion at-a-time what you wanted?

Comment: When I open the first toggle, only toggle one content should open, when clicked on second toggle then the toggle one content should close and only toggle second content should be open(Only one toggle should be open at a time)

Comment: @Inception_K That's what the FAQ section in the webpage you linked is doing, and that's what the code in my answer should also be doing. Is that webpage *not* your code running?

Comment: Yes that's correct It's working. everytime i am getting same content. In webpage you can see the content is different inside different toggle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236590/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-inception-k).

Answer (score 0):

You can do by move `isOpen` to the `FAQ` component and using `map` to return `questions`

in the FAQ:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(null);

const onClick = (i) => {
  setOpen(open === i ? null : i);
};

{
  questions.map((question, i) => (
    <Question key={i} question={question} isOpen={open === i} toggle={() => onClick(i)} />
  ));
}
```

in the Question

```
const Question = ({isOpen, toggle, question}) => {
  ...
  <button onClick={props.toggle}>
     {isOpen ? <FaMinus /> : <FaPlus />}
  </button>
  ...
  <div onClick={toggle} className="title">
    {question}
  </div>
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you please check out the question I have UPDATED with a demo of the toggle feature